# POST Call With no Body Gives 411 in Mule

Tags: mule

I'm attempting to create a mule api call an asp .net API that is a POST call. This call takes in query parameters, but no post body. When attempting to set the call up in Mule, I am returning a 411 status, the cause seemingly being that Mule does not like the POST call with no post body. Is there a way to configure the http call to accept a POST with only query parameters in Mule?

Comment: Does this help at all? https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Troubleshooting-HTTP-1-1-411-Length-Required-error-while-using-HTTP-Requester

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting an empty string as the payload:

```
<http:request method="POST" config-ref="httpRequestConfig" path="/api">
         <http:body ><![CDATA[#[""]]]></http:body>
</http:request>
```

Or for mule 3:

```
<set-payload value="#['']" />
<http:request method="POST" config-ref="httpRequestConfig" path="/api"/>
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, I like your suggestion, but this isn't working for me. I'm getting the following error: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'http:body'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":request-builder, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":success-status-code-validator, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":failure-status-code-validator}' is expected.` Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Should the body tag go before or after the request-builder?

Comment: Oh are you using mule 3? Updated answer for mule 3

Comment: Thanks, I actually fixed the problem with a set payload component: `<set-payload value="#[payload != null ? payload : &quot;&quot;]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>` before the http request.